# vba delete do while

Tags: excel, vba, loops, excel-formula, do-while

I have a problem with one code.
Please help me to fix this.

There is my code :

```
  Sub delete()
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim art As Long
    art = 2
    x = "programing"
        Do While art < Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Workbooks("11.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("f:f")) + 1
            If cell(art, 6).Value <> x Then
            cell.ClearContents
            End If
            art = art + 1
        Loop


End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: For a starter, `cell`  is not defined.  Maybe you mean `cells` ?  And which cell(s) you want to clear? And be carefull, `cells` will refer to `ActiveSheet` unless you tell VBA otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, replace cell with cells.

Secondly you should give the worksheet name as well before cells.

like worksheets(1).cells

If you make these correction, your code will run properly.

Answer (score 0):

You probably made mistake in "cell" must be "Cells".

Comment: O yea, probably i will check this. Thank you :)